# .java files of android that initiates the installation of new apk files in android

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-install-apk

Can someone help me with the installation steps in android.Specifically I want to know the .java files of android that initiates the installation of new apk files that includes parsing of manifest files and validating them.

Answer (score 0):

In android application first starts from the main Activity that you signed in your manifest file.So you can think of the java file that includes your main Activity.

onCreate() is the first method that fired automatically when android application starts

Comment: Sorry i think i made the question hard to understand.I was actually speaking of the system level installation i.e what java file in andoid source code starts the installation of new apk files.